# SSL_connect from a client while the server is in SSL_read

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I have a non-blocking socket and using select to handle connections from multiple SSL clients :

I have tried suggestions regarding handling SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, like repeat SSL_read call, or return back to Select, but it seems to be not working in my case.

```
while (1)
   {
   start:      
      if (readyCount = select(FD_SETSIZE, &read_fd_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout) < 0)
      {
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; ++i)
         if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fd_set))
         {
            if (i == sockfd)
            {               
               newSocket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientname, (socklen_t*)&size);                              
            }
            else
            {
               ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
               SSL_set_fd(ssl, i);
            accept:
               int err = SSL_accept(ssl);
               if (0 >= err)
               {                    // it never goes here 
                  int resultCode = SSL_get_error(ssl, err);
                  switch (resultCode)
                  {                 
                     case SSL_ERROR_NONE:
                        goto accept;
                        break;
                     case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:
                        SSL_shutdown(ssl);                        
                        break;
                     case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:                     
                        break;
                     case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                        break;
                     case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                        break;
                     case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT:
                        break;
                     case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT:
                        goto accept;
                        break;
                     case SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP:
                        break;
                     case SSL_ERROR_SSL:
                        break;                     }
                     default:
                        break;
                  }
               }
               else
               {
                  Call_Read(...)
               }

               SSL_free(ssl);
               close(i);
               FD_CLR(i, &active_fd_set);
            }
         }
   }   


Call_Read(...)
{   
   int fd = SSL_get_fd(ssl);
   fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK);

   while (data_size > 0)
   {
      bytes_recv = SSL_read(ssl, data, data_size);
      if (bytes_recv <= 0)
      {
         if (SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ == SSL_get_error(ssl, bytes_recv))
         {
            testtt = SSL_pending(ssl); //always 0
            /*SSL_renegotiate(ssl);
            SSL_do_handshake(ssl);*/
            continue;
         }
         if (SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE == SSL_get_error(ssl, bytes_recv))
         {            
            testtt = SSL_pending(ssl);
            int blocked_on_SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE = 1;                        
            continue;         }
         }
         return bytes_recv;
      }

      data += bytes_recv;
      data_size -= bytes_recv;
   }
   return 1;
}

Client Write:
{
while (data_size > 0)
      {
         bytes_sent = SSL_write(ssl, data_ptr, data_size);
         if (errno == EPIPE) == doesn’t reach this line, debugger stops with EPIPE
         {
            printf("WRITE socket returned EPIPE”);
            return -1;
         }

         if (bytes_sent < 0)
         {
            int err = SSL_get_error(ssl, bytes_sent);
            switch (err)
            {
               case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
                  printf(" SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ\n");
               case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
                  printf(" SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE\n");
               default:
                  ;
            }
         }         

         data_ptr += bytes_sent;
         data_size -= bytes_sent;
      }

      return 1;
   }
```

I don’t know how to handle the situation, when the server is in SSL_Read and some of clients calls SSL_Connect.

In such a scenario, the Call_Read will be in infinite loop for SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ. If I replace the “continue” statement with a flag that will finish the loop and the caller returns back to Select the client will break with broken pipe error, and it even doesn’t reach the line “WRITE socket returned EPIPE”.  The same will happen if I return from the read loop back to Accept, instead of to Select.

I am missing here something and I am wondering if I should do some changes to the client also.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You should be using non-blocking mode,so the server won't be in any I/O function for long, and you shouldn't calling `SSL_Read()` unless there is something to read, as signalled by `select()`. Your code is all wrong.

Comment: The socket us in non blocking mode set up when master socket is created. Also the select is going through code only when readcount is positive. I by mistake deleted the checking while oreparing the code example for this question.  I will edit the posting.

Comment: If you want to suppress the SIGPIPE signals, you can do so by calling `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);` at the start of your program.

Comment: Yes, I have used it, but still I get the SIGPIPE sometimes during debugging. Now I managed to get all data from multiple clients to the server, but I  end up in a loop with SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ on both sides. I am not sure what should be the condition to break the loop.

Comment: @query when you get `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`, it means an operation is running in non-blocking mode and needs to read data when no data is available. You are expected to use `select()` or `(e)poll()` to wait for the socket to enter a readable state indicating new data has arrived, and then retry the same operation that wanted to read data. Same with `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` and waiting for writability.

Comment: @user207421 "*you shouldn't calling `SSL_Read()` unless there is something to read, as signalled by `select()`*" - that is true for *tradition* non-blocking socket I/O, but that is NOT the case with OpenSSL, which DOES NOT follow traditional I/O semantics. You SHOULD NOT call `select()` *unless* an SSL operation explicitly asks you to by returning `SSL_ERROR_WANT_(READ|WRITE)`.

Comment: I added select into SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ block and if > 0 returned to ssl_read  on the server. On the client I did the same for SSL_connect (I tried with loop with select and without it also). The result is the same. The server is in a loop for error_want read, the client is in the loop for ssl_connect. This happens when SSLconnect is issued from multiple threads at the time when the server is in SSL_read. The treads on the client don't share anything from openssl (at east it was my intent)